How to solve N+1 problem for entity with multiple collections in OneToMany relationship in Spring JPA
I have the following entity and repository in my Spring JPA application (simplified for the sake of this example):
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    val id: UUID

    @OneToOne
    val info: UserInfo

    @OneToMany
    val documents: List<Document>

    @OneToMany
    val posts: List<Post>
}

interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

    @Query("custom query defined here")
    fun findAllWithCustomQuery(): List<User>

}

After calling the method findAllWithCustomQuery I faced the N+1 problem. So I tried to create an EntityGraph to solve this problem. First I tried to create it only for the UserInfo relationship, and it worked fine (no extra query was executed to fetch UserInfo).
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "graph.User", // I referenced this name in the repository method
    attributeNodes = [
        NamedAttributeNode("userInfo")
    ]
)
class User {
    @Id
    val id: UUID

    @OneToOne
    val info: UserInfo

    @OneToMany
    val documents: List<Document>

    @OneToMany
    val posts: List<Post>
}

But then I tried to apply the same approach for the documents and posts
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "graph.User", // I referenced this name in the repository method
    attributeNodes = [
        NamedAttributeNode("userInfo"),
        NamedAttributeNode("documents"),
        NamedAttributeNode("posts")
    ]
)
class User {
    @Id
    val id: UUID

    @OneToOne
    val info: UserInfo

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val documents: List<Document>

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val posts: List<Post>
}

And it threw an exception with the error cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags. I searched online and one of the solutions suggested using Set instead of List. I'm not sure if that would be ideal as it would generate a cartesian product, and in my real example I have five @OneToManyrelationships, which could lead to even worse performance issues. Besides that, I cannot find or think of another solution to this problem as it seems not feasible from a query perspective.
Is there a way to fetch all the information that I need (multiple users and their related documents and posts) in a single query? If not, is there a way to predict if the cartesian product would indeed be a problem or not?

I would expect that the definitions of the Document and Post entities are relevant. Perhaps also the definition of the UserInfo entity.

If you're forcing FetchType.EAGER on all your relationships then you're probably not gaining any advantage from your entity graph.

Using JOIN FETCH  to Solve the N+1 Problem
Here are the most common strategies to solve the N+1 problem in Spring JPA

@JohnBollinger for simplicity, they only have their Id and their reference back to the user as OneToOne and ManyToOne. I'm not sure if LAZY would be a solution because as soon as they are fetche, they are instantly converted to another model, so the lazy properties would be fetched anyway, but in a different query. Am I being too naive by thinking that it could all be returned in the same query?

@SachinKumar That did solve the problem for the OneToOne relationship, but how would that be possible for the OneToMany as there could be multiple Documentor Post being returned?

I'm not sure either whether FetchType.LAZY would be a solution. The point was that if you're annotating the relationships with FetchType.EAGER then it is redundant to use an entity graph to specify what amounts to eager fetching.

Note also that whether you do it via a FetchType or via an entity graph, both of those mechanisms are about when the relationships are fetched, not how. Your particular storage provider might exhibit differences in how it handles the two, but if so, then that's an implementation detail.  The main difference between them from JPA's point of view is that entity graphs can be chosen dynamically.

One query isn't always the best solution when you start joining over *ToMany relationships - but it depends on the data. I would guess you are using hibernate, but some other providers have multiple batch reading options (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448803/496099). I believe Hibernate has its own: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-subselect
